# GCM Push notification returns the error message "GCM registration is not ready with auth credentials...."

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, provisioning-profile

I have to implement GCM push notification in IOS swift application.
First, I was working on the application and I followed all the tips and instructions in google documentation : https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client.
The Registration token was generated but after that I had to complete the application in another computer so I re-generated the certificates but the error "GCM registration is not ready with auth credentials" keeps showing, I tried everything and removed the certificates and follow all the instructions but I could not solve this issues.

I also tried to generated iOS Provisioning Profiles manually and I tried using Xcode but that did not solve the issue.

iOS Provisioning Profiles

Any tips to solve it.?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to test this yesterday successfully in Sandbox mode,
All my configuration was same.
And suddenly (few hours ago) it stopped working.(Also noticed that stackoverflow is full of this issue related questions within couple of hours)
This issues is not related to developer's configuration,
I think it's **google backend/api** related issues/changes.
In the mean time you could try some other steps,if you've missed some steps.
follow this issue(**The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.gcm error 501.)**)
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/205

Comment: GCM push is now working without any issues :-)
Happy Coding :-D

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error occurred because I forgot to enable `Push Notifications` in `capabilities` and also enabling `Background Modes-> Remote Notifications` in my `XCode project`. By enabling this capabilities my problem solved.